# Elastic 7 mapping definition has unsupported parameters

Tags: database, elasticsearch

I believe this issue has to do with the different syntax from elasticsearch 6.x -> 7.x
This is my first time using elasticsearch and havent been able to understand where the issue is.
How would I fix my mapping?

```
{
    "settings": {
        "analysis": {
        "analyzer": {
            "ssdeep_analyzer": {
            "tokenizer": "ssdeep_tokenizer"
            }
        },
        "tokenizer": {
            "ssdeep_tokenizer": {
            "type": "ngram",
            "min_gram": 7,
            "max_gram": 7,
            "token_chars": [
                "letter",
                "digit",
                "symbol"
            ]
            }
        }
        }
    },
    "mappings": {
        "_default_": {
        "_all": {
            "enabled": false
        },
        "dynamic": "strict",
        "properties": {
            "chunksize": {
            "type": "integer"
            },
            "chunk": {
            "analyzer": "ssdeep_analyzer",
            "type": "text"
            },
            "double_chunk": {
            "analyzer": "ssdeep_analyzer",
            "type": "text"
            },
            "ssdeep": {
            "type": "keyword"
            },
            "sha256": {
            "type": "keyword"
            }
        }
        },
        "record": {}
    }
}
```

The error that is being raised is

```
elasticsearch.exceptions.RequestError: RequestError(400, 'mapper_parsing_exception', 'Root mapping definition has unsupported parameters:  [_default_ : {dynamic=strict, _all={enabled=false}, properties={sha256={type=keyword}, chunksize={type=integer}, chunk={analyzer=ssdeep_analyzer, type=text}, double_chunk={analyzer=ssdeep_analyzer, type=text}, ssdeep={type=keyword}}}] [record : {}]')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A bunch of issues here:

- The `_all` field is deprecated (and has been [since `v6`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.8/mapping-all-field.html)).
- `"record": {}` is not a valid parameter.
- `_default_` is deprecated too.

Here's a working mapping:

```json
{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "analyzer": {
        "ssdeep_analyzer": {
          "tokenizer": "ssdeep_tokenizer"
        }
      },
      "tokenizer": {
        "ssdeep_tokenizer": {
          "type": "ngram",
          "min_gram": 7,
          "max_gram": 7,
          "token_chars": [
            "letter",
            "digit",
            "symbol"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "dynamic": "strict",
    "properties": {
      "chunksize": {
        "type": "integer"
      },
      "chunk": {
        "analyzer": "ssdeep_analyzer",
        "type": "text"
      },
      "double_chunk": {
        "analyzer": "ssdeep_analyzer",
        "type": "text"
      },
      "ssdeep": {
        "type": "keyword"
      },
      "sha256": {
        "type": "keyword"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: Would you be able to take a look at my query as well for syntax? I believe it has the same outdated problem.

Comment: I believe it has to do with the way I am comparing `"chunksize": [chunksize, chunksize * 2, int(chunksize / 2)]`

Comment: You're welcome. Can you put the 2nd question into a new question?

Comment: Asked it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66805405/elasticsearch-7-x-content-parse-exception-failed-to-parse-field-must)